# Solving Equation With Logarithm Argument Being a Variable

Tags: polynomials, logarithms, quadratics

$$8n^2 = 64n\log_{2}n$$

Been a while since I have used logarithms. I am actually comparing the running time of two algorithms and can obviously solve graphically but for the life of me can't remember the necessary steps to solve by hand. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: no closed form solution. Graphical and, if needed, numerical.

Answer (score 2):

Since $n>0$ or the logarithm doesn't exist, the equation is the same as
$$
n=8\log_2n
$$
If we consider the function $f(x)=x-8\log_2x$, we have
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\infty=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)
$$
Moreover
$$
f'(x)=1-\frac{8}{x\log 2}
$$
(natural logarithm), which vanishes for $x=\frac{8}{\log2}=8\log_2e$.

Since
$$
f(8\log_2e)=8\log_2e-8\log_2(8\log_2e)=8(\log_2e-3-\log_2\log_2e)<0
$$
there are two values where $f(x)=0$. One value is $\approx1.1$, the other one is $\approx43.56$.